# How to get filename and path of file opened in Notepad?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Is it possible to get name with path of a file opened in Notepad. I already have ProcessId of the Notepad.exe.

Thanks,
Navneet

Comment: There is no generic way to do this. Your best bet is to ask for the authors support for adding a method to get the path. There may be other ways depending on what you actually want the path for though.

Comment: Curious, what's the bigger picture here? Are you trying to do this as part of some larger task? As Deanna says, there's no good way to get the filename for notepad, but there could be some other approach for the problem.

Comment: I am writing an app and want to capture caret position of the file currently opened in the Notepad, I will take that information and then do further processing. Is it possible to somehow sub-class Notepad for this?

Comment: Do you have control over the notepad getting opened? I mean do u know when the notepad will be opened/path of the notepad before hand? just asking..

Comment: No ... I do not have control over when the Notepad will be opened.

Comment: i suppose a similar method to process monitor. By the way, notepad doesn't keep files open, it opens and closes them hence it's possible to write to files from outside, when notepad has a file open If notepad kept it open the file would be locked and you couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the title bar, so you need to get the window handle and then call the Win API function `GetWindowText()`

This might be what you want: [Getting correct window title using Process object.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8013bc78-059a-42e7-ae3e-e38960752656/)

Edit: [MSDN GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx)

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't give the full path.

Comment: This only gets you the file part of the filename, not the path, so it's only part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. for my scenario I want to get the full path as well.

Comment: if your answer is wrong then why haven't you deleted it?

Comment: @barlop Since BrendanMcK has documented the limitations of this answer, it does no harm to leave it. If somebody posts a better answer, this will be ignored, so it still does no harm to leave it.

Comment: well, since it has 3 upvotes too, it actually has the appearance of a correct answer, it fooled people,  It's only really worthy of a comment but since it's done you may want to leave it. Though also, since there's only one answer it makes it look like it has an answer.  i'll suggest an edit.. 'cos somebody might not read the comments.

Comment: Why do you say "This might be what you want"?   Are you not sure if that link even answers the getting the filename part of the question? or are you trying to suggest that it gets the path as well?

Comment: No, I originally assumed he would know how to get the window caption, that link is if he didn't.

Comment: -1: What if in a future version of Windows, they decide to change the window caption of Notepad so the filename does not appear in the caption bar?

Comment: @stackptr Notepad has worked this way for *thirty years.*